# How to make auto day selection while picking a date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I had two fields something like HolidayDate such that is following,

```
 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)] 
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 [DisplayName(Constants.DisplayName.HolidayDate)]
  public virtual DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }

 [StringLength(50)]
 [DisplayName(Constants.DisplayName.HolidayDay)]
 public virtual string HolidayDay { get; set; }
```

And in my cshtml file

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="" class="control-label">Date</label>
  <br />
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayDate, new { @class = "form-control"})
    .DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="" class="control-label">Day</label>
  <br />
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HolidayDay, new { @class = "form-control"})
    .DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)
</div>
```

If I pick a date in HolidayDate field, then the day of that date should assign in HolidayDay field automatically, so please Can anyone please help to find the solution

Comment: Show your jquery code

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

$("#HolidayDate").datepicker(
          {
              altField: "#HolidayDay",
              altFormat: "DD"
          });
      });

Comment: See the edited code.....and if you can help then please help me

Comment: Is it the jquery ui datepicker?

Comment: No..here mvc razor technique is used, So i did't use any jquery code for datepicker i used the following code.---->   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayDate, new { @class = "form-control" }).DisableIf(() => Model.IsReadOnly == true)

Comment: I used @Html.EditorFor method only for datepicker.

Comment: You mean you want to be able to do this without using the datepicker plugin?

Comment: Yes. If you know how to do it using JavaScript/Jquery, then please help me

Comment: I tried lots of ways but i can't find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#HolidayDate').change(function() {
  var date = new Date($(this).val());
  $('#HolidayDay').val(date.getDate());
});
```

or if you want to display the day of the week

```
var daysOfWeek = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
$('#HolidayDate').change(function () {
  var date = new Date($(this).val());
  $('#HolidayDay').val(daysOfWeek[d.getDay()]);
});
```

[Refer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykoy4ea3/1/)

Comment: JQuery is not working i mean this function is not called

Comment: Works for me. Do you have any browser errors? Is jquery included. Is the script at the bottom of the page? Could be any number of issues - debug it!

Comment: Can you send me the full Code, I mean from  <script>  to </scrip>

Comment: I have. Its was cut and past from a test project. Check the html generated for `HolidayDate`. It should be `<input type="date" id="Holiday" .... />`

Comment: Yes, in JSFIDDLE its working, but I want to pick a day name, not date..... Its ok I will try it in my code and tell you the issue if occur

Comment: If you wanted the day of the week that that's what your question should have said! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Then debug it in the browser console.

Comment: Anyway, Thank you so much for your response!!